# Regenerating a Cobalt Acetate Catalyst

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, metal

I have an eluent from an ion-exchange column containing Cobalt (II) ions and Chloride ions. In order for the cobalt catalyst to be recycled to the main process, it must be in its acetate form.
Is there a route from cobalt chloride to acetate that is feasible at an industrial scale?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quick Laboratory method:

$$\ce {CoCl2(aq) + 2NaOH(aq)->Co(OH)2(s) + 2NaCl(aq)}$$
$$\ce {Co(OH)2(s) + 2CH3CO2H(aq)->Co(CH3CO2)2(aq) + 2H2O(l)}$$
$$\ce {Co(CH3CO2)2(aq) + \Delta->Co(CH3CO2)2\cdot 4H2O (s)}$$

You should separate $\ce{Co(OH)2}$ by filteration and washed with water ($\pu {K_{sp} = 1.0 \times 10^{-15}}$) to remove all $\ce{NaCl}$ before subjected to react with $\ce{CH3CO2H}$.

This might work in industrial scale, if be careful. $\ce{Co(OH)2}$ is unstable to heat but no need to dry before react with $\ce{CH3CO2H}$.

Comment: Care should be taken in the presence of complexants as ammonia or too high pH values that might form soluble cobaltates.

Comment: @aventurin: You are absolutely correct. Thank you for the valuable point.

Answer (score -3):

add sodium sulphide solution -> precipitate  cobalt sulphide complex ( highly stable ) -> filter - dissolve in acetic acid